# Unable to save URL image to Android studio emulator SD card,getting open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)

Tags: android, emulation, android-sdcard

I am not able to save URL image on my android studio emulator SD card ,I am getting no such file and directory error.

```
/**
 * Background Async Task to download file
 * */
class DownloadFileFromURL extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        /**
         * Before starting background thread
         * Show Progress Bar Dialog
         * */
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            showDialog(progress_bar_type);
        }

        /**
         * Downloading file in background thread
         * */
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... f_url) {
            int count;
            try {
                URL url = new URL(f_url[0]);
                URLConnection conection = url.openConnection();
                conection.connect();
                // getting file length
                int lenghtOfFile = conection.getContentLength();

                // input stream to read file - with 8k buffer
                InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream(), 8192);

                // Output stream to write file
                OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream("/sdcard/Download/downloadedfile.jpg");

                byte data[] = new byte[1024];

                long total = 0;

                while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
                    total += count;
                    // publishing the progress....
                    // After this onProgressUpdate will be called
                    publishProgress(""+(int)((total*100)/lenghtOfFile));

                    // writing data to file
                    output.write(data, 0, count);
                }

                // flushing output
                output.flush();

                // closing streams
                output.close();
                input.close();

            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
            }

            return null;
        }

        /**
         * Updating progress bar
         * */
        protected void onProgressUpdate(String... progress) {
            // setting progress percentage
            pDialog.setProgress(Integer.parseInt(progress[0]));
       }

        /**
         * After completing background task
         * Dismiss the progress dialog
         * **/
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
            // dismiss the dialog after the file was downloaded
            dismissDialog(progress_bar_type);

            // Displaying downloaded image into image view
            // Reading image path from sdcard
            String imagePath = "/sdcard/Download/downloadedfile.jpg";
            // setting downloaded into image view
            my_image.setImageDrawable(Drawable.createFromPath(imagePath));
        }

    }
}
```

not able to save image in Android studio emulator SD card where I have to save it in imageview.

I am getting this error.

```
com.example.androidhive E/Error:: /sdcard/Download/downloadedfile.jpg: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
com.example.androidhive E/Surface: getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0xac1b6c70
com.example.androidhive E/BitmapFactory: Unable to decode stream:
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /sdcard/Download/downloadedfile.jpg: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add permission in AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"></uses-permission>
```

Comment: It is already there.The problem is something related to path of SD card I think.

Comment: Is the folder "/sdcard/Download" in SD card? create the folder at first.